# $group stage returns zero documents despite previous stage outputting a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

[Reproduction in Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yzJAPHwv67f)

I have an aggregation pipeline which contains a `$lookup` stage then a `$match` stage and then a `$group` stage.

Oddly (to me anyway), while the `$match` stage outputs a document (as can be seen by temporarily removing the `$group` stage), the `$group` stage after it outputs zero documents. If a `$group` stage has any input documents, I expect it will always have at least one output document. Why is that not the case here?

The above Mongo playground link reproduces the behavior in question.

Here is the aggregation pipeline which outputs zero documents:

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "products.0.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "firstProduct"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "firstProduct.0.name": "Apron"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "numOrders": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Here is the same pipeline with the group stage removed. It returns one document.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "products.0.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "firstProduct"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "firstProduct.0.name": "Apron"
    }
  }
]);
```

Here is the contents of the `orders` collection:

```json
[
  {
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": {
          "$oid": "00000001f1438712ca040fca"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is the contents of the `products` collection:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Apron",
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "00000001f1438712ca040fca"
    }
  }
]
```

MongoDB version is 6.0.4. I also tried in 4.4.19 and the behavior is the same.

Comment: When I run that pipeline locally I get a single doc with `_id` of `null` and `numOrders` set to 1.   This is v6.0.4.

Comment: That's odd. I get nothing, same as in the Mongo Playground link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the same behaviour on v5.0.2
When I looked at the explain plan, there is projection stage being added whenever, there you have group stage in the pipeline.

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
    "transformBy" : {
        "firstProduct" : 1,
        "products.0.productId" : 1,
        "_id" : 0
    },
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "direction" : "forward"
    }
}
```

You can recreate the issue with this stage added in your aggregate query.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "products.0.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "firstProduct"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
       "firstProduct" : 1,
       "products.0.productId" : 1,
       "_id" : 0
    }
  }
])
```

Result

```
{
    "products" : [ 
        {}
    ],
    "firstProduct" : []
}
```

I think, specifying 0 index, is messing some optimisations under the hood. Removing the index, it is working as expected.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "products.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "firstProduct"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "firstProduct.name": "Apron"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "numOrders": {$sum: 1}
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Sounds like JIRA-worthy bug?